# Access a form's control by name

Tags: vb.net, winforms

not sure whether the title of this post is accurate.
I'm trying to access windows form controls and their properties by "composing" their name within a loop, but I can't seem to find the related documentation. Using VB.net. Basically, say I have the following:

```
Dim myDt As New DataTable

Dim row As DataRow = myDt.NewRow()

row.Item("col01") = Me.label01.Text
row.Item("col02") = Me.label02.Text
'...
row.Item("colN") = Me.labelN.Text
```

I'd like to write a for loop instead of N separate instructions.
While it's simple enough to express the left-hand side of the assignments, I'm stumped when it comes to the right-hand side:

```
For i As Integer = 1 to N
    row.Item(String.format("col{0:00}", i)) = ???
    ' ??? <- write "label" & i (zero-padded, like col) and use that string to access Me's control that has such name
Next
```

As an extra, I'd like to be able to pass the final ".Text" property as a string as well, for in some cases I need the value of the "Text" property, in other cases the value of the "Value" property; generally speaking, the property I'm interested in might be a function of i.

Cheers.

Comment: NB: I have tried with `Me.Controls("label" & i)` but it doesn't work for me! Possibly because labels are nested inside other controls (such as XtraTabPages in XtraTabControls and so on...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [ControlsCollection.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with the `searchAllChildren` option set to true

```
For i As Integer = 1 to N
    Dim ctrl = Me.Controls.Find(string.Format("label{0:00}", i), True)
    if ctrl IsNot Nothing AndAlso ctrl.Length > 0 Then
        row.Item(String.format("col{0:00}", i)) = ctrl(0).Text
    End If
Next
```

An example on how to approach the problem using reflection to set a property that you identify using a string

```
Dim myLabel As Label = new Label()
Dim prop as PropertyInfo = myLabel.GetType().GetProperty("Text")
prop.SetValue(myLabel, "A Label.Text set with Reflection classes", Nothing)
Dim newText = prop.GetValue(myLabel)
Console.WriteLine(newText)
```

Comment: It is best to avoid hiding bugs.  Exceptions are a Good Thing.

Comment: Super. Now if only I could access the control's property by name (also passed as string) that's be awesome. Instead of `ctrl(0).Text` something like `ctrl(0).GetProperty("Text")` since the property I want to fetch depends on the value of `i` (hence will be something of the sort: `ctrl(0).GetProperty(f(i))`, where `f` returns a string). Cheers.